# Android - Doubt in google sample application code

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-layout

I am about to do some android source code modifications. SO, as a first step, I was referring the codes written by google after downloading it from git.

Initially, I was referring the 'Home' sample app provided by google(development/samples/Home).

I saw this xml in that application and I noticed that, the syntax was quite different from the normal xml layouts for the apps. I did not understand the code which comes inside "" block in the xml. It points to some class -- com.example.android.home.ApplicationsStackLayout .

Can someone kindly guide, as to how this [xml](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/res/layout-port/home.html) - [class](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/src/com/example/android/home/ApplicationsStackLayout.html) duo works?

On a footnote, I would like to add that, understanding android open source code is a bit difficult, as we do not have much of resources available as in the case of android application development.Other than the [google community](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform?pli=1), are there any good, useful and helpful resources in the form of books, blogs or forums to understand better and dwelve more into the google android source?

Any help in this regard would be well appreciated.

Best Regards,
Rony

Answer (score 1):

The android systems parses the given xml. For every note it instantiates a view or a layout depending on the node type. There are some built-in layouts and views: TextView, EditTextView, LinearLayout and so on. If you want to customize your view or layout you write a class which inherits from View or layout. `ApplicationsStackLayout` is an example of custom layout.

As for resources, look at this good [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114287/good-book-for-beginning-android-development).